# Powershell Compare-Object compare ad users not in list of groups

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find all users that have mailboxes, but are not in some expected groups (where we put our users we expect to have mailboxes).  I've gotten it working in my script, but the way I did it is to loop through the collection of user accounts and verify their memberships individually.....which is excruciatingly slow.  I'm trying to instead compare the (sorted) list of user accounts to the (sorted unique list) of those in the member groups....but not having success with the compare-object command.

$GrpMembersUnique is the sorted list of unique accounts in the various groups

```
$GrpMembersUnique = Get-AdGroup -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=blahblah" -filter {name -eq 'GRP_STAFF' -OR name -eq 'GRP_2' ....} -properties member | select-object -ExpandProperty member | get-AdUser -properties SamAccountName | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
```

$userlist is the sorted list of unique accounts with mailboxes

```
$userlist=Get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=People,DC=blahblah" -filter {mail -like "*" } -properties mail,SamAccountName | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
```

Compare command:

```
$ChecklList = compare-object -ReferenceObject $userlist -DifferenceObject $GrpMembersUnique -ExcludeDifferent -Property 'SamAccountName' | Where {$_.SideIndicator -like "<="}
```

returns no results.  this should be simple, so I'm thinking I missed something easy....any help or guidance appreciated.

Comment: your command is excluding all those that are not in both. [*grin*] look at the output of this `Get-Help Compare-Object -Parameter ExcludeDifferent` and note `Indicates that this cmdlet displays only the characteristics of compared objects that are equal.`

Comment: Can you paste some sample data of the `$userlist` and `$GrpMembersUnique` in the question?

Comment: Sure.  I'll add to the original post so I can format better.....

Comment: Thanks Lee.  I did try without the -ExcludeDifferent switch....but got the same results (should posted that earlier).  Meaning, tried the command as such with no luck:  $ChecklList = compare-object -ReferenceObject $userlist -DifferenceObject $GrpMembersUnique -Property SamAccountName | Where {$_.SideIndicator -like "<="}

Comment: Thanks again Lee.  That hint steered me in the right direction.  added the -IncludeEqual switch instead, and works now.  full command now reads:  `compare-object -ReferenceObject $userlist -DifferenceObject $GrpMembersUnique -IncludeEqual -Property 'SamAccountName' | Where {$_.SideIndicator -like "<="} `

Comment: @Jeff - kool! glad to know you got it working ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Using wrong switch.  Changed -ExcludeDifferent to -IncludeEqual, and working as expected now.  Thanks Lee_Dailey.

```
compare-object -ReferenceObject $userlist -DifferenceObject $GrpMembersUnique -IncludeEqual -Property 'SamAccountName' | Where {$_.SideIndicator -like "<="}
```